# Using StringReader to read to the end of String

Tags: java, java-io, stringreader

How can I use a StringReader in Java to read to the end of a string, where I don't know what the length of the string will be.

This is how far I've gotten so far:

```
public static boolean portForward(Device dev, int localPort, int remotePort)
{
    boolean success = false;
    AdbCommand adbCmd = Adb.formAdbCommand(dev, "forward", "tcp:" + localPort, "tcp:" + remotePort);
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(executeAdbCommand(adbCmd));
    try
    {
        if (/*This is what's missing :/ */)
        {
            success = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There was an error while retrieving the list of devices.\n" + ex + "\nPlease report this error to the developer/s.", "Error Retrieving Devices", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: Well what are you trying to do with the string? It's very unclear what condition you're trying to check for.

Comment: Well, I just want to check if it's empty. To be fairly honest.

Comment: StringReader is, more or less, the same as any Reader, so pretend that this is a file, how would you do what you want?

Comment: @Beatsleigher: Why bother with a `StringReader` at all? Just use `String.isEmpty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment to your question, where you basically say that you just want to verify that the string is empty.

```
if (reader.read() == -1)
{
   // There is nothing in the stream, way to go!!
   success = true;
}
```

or, even simpler:

```
String result = executeAdbCommand(adbCmd);
success = result.length() == 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String all = executeAdbCommand(adbCmd);
if (all.isEmpty()) {
}
```

Normally a StringReader is used to read/process piecewise, and does not really fit here.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
   new StringReader(executeAdbCommand(adbCmd)));
try
{ce
    for (;;)
    {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null)
            break;
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "...",
        "Error Retrieving Devices", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
```